# A paradox at the heart of the Brexit argument

Tags: brexit

It is central to the argument of the campaign to leave the EU, that Britain needs "trade agreements" with the non-EU world. (Forget for one moment that we do enjoy such agreements with about 70 countries by virtue of our membership of the EU)

Why is it important to Brexiters to have trade agreements with the Far East, Africa, Australasia and the Americas? Indeed any suggestion we should be in the EU Customs Union draws howls of protest from Brexiters. They say it would mean we could not have independent trade agreements elsewhere.

However Brexiters are perfectly happy to trade with Europe, by far our largest trading partner on WTO terms. So if WTO terms are ok for trade with the EU, why not with China, America, India etc?

**This is a central paradox in the Brexit argument, which so far no Brexiter has been able to explain to me.** I heard David Gauke, the Justice Secretary, also mention his own failure to get an answer to the question.

I'm not looking to have an argument here, simply an explanation.

Comment: Who says they want to trade mostly with the EU? Maybe they want to trade a lot with all the other countries? As it stands, I think it's mostly speculation, and as such I think it's very hard to answer. Different Brexiteers may have different views on this just like different liberals may have different views on trade.

Comment: @JJJ There is nothing preventing Britain trading with the non-EU world at the moment. Germany is subject to the same Customs Union rules and sells six times as much as Britain in dollar value outside the EU every year. France, Italy and the Netherlands all sell more than the UK. In fact our non-EU trade is about the same as that of Belgium - a country one-sixth our size. It is not membership of the Customs Union which hampers Britain's export trade, it is the lack of attractive products to sell.

Comment: Is that really central?  My impression has been that the main argument is that many Britons (and people in other EU countries) detest the multitude of rules imposed on them by Brussels bureaucrats.  I would guess that most Brexit voters don't really care about trade agreements.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Even if that were a central point in brexiter policy the [diagram shown by Barnier](https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-eu-options/stairway-to-brexit-barnier-maps-out-uks-canadian-path-idUKKBN1ED23R) still gives the possibility for a Canada style deal, which is incomparably better than WTO terms. I feel the no deal option to be a political argument, not an a pragmatic one. Moreover I think the argument was that trade with EU could be replaced by trade deals with other markets with a positive balance. This is seen as unlikely thus the lack of consensus among Tories.

Answer (score 12):

Brexiteers are not a monolithic block and not uniquely devoid of paradoxes. However, the principle would be:

> We want a trade deal with Europe, USA, Japan etc that does not require us being part of a supranational political organisation. If we cannot get such a deal that meets the interests of the UK, we are happy to trade on WTO terms with Europe, USA, Japan etc.

Very few brexiteers say that WTO terms are their preference for dealings with the EU. They want a trade deal to include zero tariffs on a wide range of goods. However, if such a deal is not available then (and only then) they would be willing to accept the fallback position of the WTO rules.

Similarly, they do not want WTO rules for trade with (say) Japan, and want to be able to negotiate a deal with Japan that is advantageous to the UK. It is the belief that the UK negotiating only for itself can get a more advantageous deal than the EU can, negotiating for the benefit of all the countries in the bloc.

So the claim has never been that WTO is both better and worse. Instead it is  the claim that the costs of EU membership (money, pooling/loss of sovereignty, inability to make bespoke trade deals, loss of control of immigration) do not justify the benefits (EU grants, free trade in Europe, influence on very large economic bloc, access to EU trade deals, freedom of movement for UK citizens across Europe)

Comment: There is nothing much here with which one can disagree, but it doesn't seem to me to explain why, for example the hard Brexiters are so opposed to the UK remaining in the Customs Union. Could we possibly sign trade deals with elsewhere e.g. Japan, that gave us such advantage over what the EU trade deal with that country gives us, that it compensated for the loss of a trade agreement with the EU and the other 69 countries with which it has dealings?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question. The assumption of many brexiteers is "yes, we can negotiate such deals"

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Yes. To begin with the emphasis was on trade and how much better we could do outside the EU. But as that argument has been worn down, some Brexiters quite accept that it is spurious. But they have switched to the idea of Britain recovering its "sovereignty" over its laws etc - sovereignty which we have managed perfectly well without for the last 40 years mind. The third major strand was of course about "free movement". I'm not too sure why, but that seems to have gone far quieter. Immigration figures have remained virtually what they were, but with more non-EU and fewer EU.

Comment: @WS2 in short, remaining in the customs union means we also have to give up a lot of control to the EU as well, something a lot of brexiteers want to stop.  A customs union doesn't come by itself.

Comment: @Moo The Customs Union means that instead of 27 countries individually having to manage their trade relations, Brussels does it for all of them. The saving in cost is enormous, and without it Britain would certainly not have been able to reduce government expenditure to the extent it has over the last forty years. Some Conservative think it was Margaret Thatcher who reduced the size of the British state. The secret is that it was the EU bureaucracy, so often maligned. But Brexit will have its compensations. There should be a flood of graduate openings in Whitehall again. Pity the taxpayer!

Comment: @WS2 as I try to explain in my answer: it's not that Brexiteers don't want a trade deal/customs union, it's that they don't want the baggage of open borders/political integration that the EU is trying to impose on us along with it. Also, you mention above that immigration figures haven't changed. True ... but we haven't left yet! ;)

Comment: Can you give us a source for the quote?

Comment: Don't they realise that WTO is a "supranational political organisation"? And one on which they have completely no influence?

Comment: @WS2: why don't you ask that question about hard Brexiteers and a customs union separately?

Comment: @WS2: also (in a later comment) you seem to miss the distinction between *the* Customs Union that comes with the Single Market and *a* customs union like Turkey has or like the UK would have under the Withdrawal Agreement (as long as the backstop is in place). Turkey for example can strike some trade deals on its own: https://www.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-eu-customsunion/pros-and-cons-of-a-customs-union-for-brexit-britain-idUSKCN1RD1XD

Comment: @WS2: Actually since that has a pretty trivial answer, Rees-Mogg said that a customs' union is the same thing as staying in the EU from his perspective https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=1997024383896884

Answer (score 3):

I voted to leave, and to answer your question the way I see it:

It's not that Brexit voters don't want to trade with Europe, or have a trade agreement with them. Of course they do - the EU is the UK's largest trading partner, so why wouldn't we want a trade agreement? However, Brexit is really a rejection of the *terms* of the trade deal that is being insisted on by the EU. Brexiteers are generally happy to trade, but they reject this apparent philosphy of the EU that trade must be accompanied by open borders and ever closer political integration. As far as my own position: trade - yes please; political integration - no thanks!

Comment: You have not mentioned where you stand on the Customs Union and the Single Market. As one old enough to have been earning his living whilst our economy was a basket case in the 60s and early 70s, my guess is that both of these have contributed to our much improved economic performance over the last 45 years. If you are agreeable to the CU and SM, my guess is that your position is not far removed from Ken Clarke's. He advocates staying in the economic arrangements but out of the political. Some argue it commits us to something over which we lose all control - a dependent colony of the EU.

Comment: If we are getting a bad deal from the EU, there is a fair chance that some other countries are too. I can't believe that all the remaining 27 are simply benefitting at the expense of the UK. So instead of getting out, why don't we join forces with other like countries, to improve our position, within the EU. I still can't help thinking that this whole Brexit debacle is more about protecting the Conservative party from Farage, who in turn is kept in business by tabloid newspapers who find themselves inside a shrinking market with the demise of print journalism.

Comment: Yes, I sympathize with the views you describe in your first comment. If a form of customs union or single market could be implemented without the political/territorial integration (something like NAFTA), then I would be fine with that. As for your last point: many leave voters are from areas that traditionally vote Labour, so I don't agree that it is solely a result of Tory party politics (I am myself left-leaning). UKIP was a rising force in UK politics before the referendum. Imo, it really seems to defy traditional political boundaries.

Comment: Tom Watson, writing in today's Observer, says that for every vote that Labour has lost to Brexit in Thursday's election, they have lost four to the Liberal Democrats. He argues for the party to support a "people's vote". I believe that if Labour came out lock, stock and barrel for Remain, with a staunch Remainer, such as David Miliband at the helm, they would sweep into power. They might lose a couple of seats in the north, but they would potentially pick up far more from the Remain vote everywhere else.

Comment: @WS2 I don't want to get into a long discussion, as that isn't what the comments here are for. However, the Brexit party seems to have won the EU elections in the UK today by a clear margin.

Comment: This is incorrect. I have already written this in the OP but I'll repeat here: [Barnier mapped the options in a diagram](https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-eu-options/stairway-to-brexit-barnier-maps-out-uks-canadian-path-idUKKBN1ED23R). There is clearly a Canada style option in there, which was refused by the UK. The idea that the EU refused to offer the UK the same that offered others is at best, negligent, and at worst deliberate misinformation. This is public information reported by several international agencies, including from the UK (as can be seen in the link).

Comment: @Time4Tea Whilst the parties supporting no-deal got 31.6% of the vote, those supporting a "People's Vote" got 40.3%. So I'm not clear on how Brexit won? All I will say is that I cannot imagine who in their right mind would want to be Prime Minister at the moment!

Comment: @armatita your point about the Canada-style option is fair enough and I have removed that second para (it wasn't essential to the point I was trying to make in answering the question anyway).

Comment: @WS2 That topic is being discussed in this other question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41757/did-the-brexit-party-dominate-eu-elections-in-the-uk. I think we should bear in mind that the votes for the Brexit Party are specifically those that support a *no-deal*, which I would expect to be a subset of those that support Brexit.

Comment: @Time4Tea In that case you should also be aware that already in 1957, in the [Treaty of Rome](https://www.equalrightstrust.org/sites/default/files/ertdocs//rometreaty.pdf) (creation of the EEC, and almost two decades prior to UK accession), there were already provisions for free mobility among other integrationist policies (Article 48, for example). So the last paragraph is a bit off the mark. The same for the first. When the UK first entered the EEC it already knew of its project. None of it was imposed (all members have veto power, decisions by consensus). A gun to the head argument is void.

Comment: @armatita ok, that's interesting and I have to admit that I wasn't aware that political integration was always a goal of the EEC right from the start. I will read some more into that and I have deleted the last paragraph of my answer. However, in the first para, I am merely trying to give some insight into my own position (and the Brexit case, in general). So, I fail to see how that can be 'off the mark' (unless because you simply disagree with the opinion).

Comment: @Time4Tea My issue with the first paragraph is the word **imposed**. It might be how you perceive it but that does not make it true. The implication alone require some kind of proof of source to what is essentially a claim. Moreover you are not the only person on this site with similar views. Although sad, leaving the EU is a right, nothing wrong with that. But why do the rest of us need to be tyrants, soviet union alikes, impose(rs), etc., to justify the act? Why is it so easy to write something that seems so implausible (like the EU deliberately discriminating the UK)?

Comment: @armatita I have changed 'imposed' to 'insisted on' in my answer. Hopefully that will seem fair, as the EU is effectively 'insisting on' certain terms being attached to a free trade deal, which the Brexit side is rejecting.

Answer (score -2):

I have no skin in this game, so I am cannot speak for Brexiters.  But I can understand the argument.  I'll state it, but don't take it to mean that I am endorsing it.

WTO rules are more macro-scale.  For example, they rarely get into forcing rules of trade of a particular product.

If you consider the whole situation on a smaller scale, 2 corporations making a deal would not want a government telling them that they can trade some *specific* goods and services, but not the others.  A government would, of course, be tempted to weigh in on anything that it may be allowed to weigh in on.  But the more micro-scale control it has, the less of that control is left in the hands of the owners.

This is the *difference*. I am not saying one is better than the other.  There will be some winners and some losers in both scenarios.  Ultimately, it is the political process that will decide on which future the country prefers.

Comment: Are you kidding? The UK's WTO schedule for goods is some 715 pages long. The one for services some extra 94 pages. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-goods-and-services-schedules-at-the-wto

Comment: @Fizz at 20-30 line items per page, that's 15000 - 20000 items.  Is that for the entire UK?  If it is, it seems more like an exception than the rule.  For perspective, Sears catalog had 322 pages in 1894!

Comment: @Fizz as another example, there is  12,000,000 items [sold by Amazon](https://www.retailtouchpoints.com/resources/type/infographics/how-many-products-does-amazon-carry/).  That's not 12M sales, that's 12M items that they sell. Surely, you must agree that even the generous estimate of 25,000 items in UK's WTO schedule is a very small fraction of the marketplace.