# Did the Brexit Party "dominate" EU elections in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, brexit, european-parliament, brexit-party

According to the BBC headline the Brexit Part "dominated" the EU election results:

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-48417228

Yet if you look at the actual numbers it seems that they polled only 31.6% of the vote. If you add up all the **explicitly** pro-brexit parties (Brexit + UKIP) and all the **explicitly** pro-remain parties (Lib Dems, Greens, Plaid, SNP, Change UK) you get:

Pro Brexit: 34.9%
Pro Remain: 40.3%

So to me it seems like the Remain side won by quite a large margin.

Did the Brexit Party "dominate" EU elections in the UK?

Comment: The Conservatives are Pro-Brexit. Labelling them otherwise is just silly.

Comment: Labour and the Conservatives combined made up 23% of the vote. Both of those parties officially support 'delivering Brexit', and it's not clear how many people who voted for those parties are pro/anti Brexit.

Comment: The Tories are split on Brexit and have failed to deliver it. They were unable to propose any specific plan for Brexit in their manifesto. As such people wanting to explicitly support Brexit have turned away from them. Labour is split on Brexit and can't state a clear position, e.g. do they want a confirmatory referendum or not? As such anyone wanting to explicitly support remaining would have to vote for a different party. That's why I used the word "explicitly".

Comment: The Tories are split on the Kind of Brexit, rather than on Brexit. 2nd Referendum or remain Tories are single figure totals. Only if you call Change UK a split can it be said the Tories are split on Brexit.

Comment: The BBC pretty much contradicts itself (the graph they have indeed has the split you indicate with the Tories and Labour counted separated).  I guess their text and headline editors didn't see eye to eye on this... so this is clearly going to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: Maybe the best comment on that is Kussenberg's: "Were these results an overwhelming cry for us to leave the EU whatever the cost? Or a sign, with some slightly convoluted arithmetic, that the country now wants another referendum to stop Brexit all together? Guess what, the situation is not quite so black and white, whatever you will hear in the coming hours about the meaning of these numbers. The Brexit Party's success was significant and Nigel Farage's new group is the biggest single winner. But the Lib Dems, Greens, Plaid and SNP - all parties advocating the opposite - were victors too."

Comment: CNN had a more grounded [analysis](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/05/27/europe/european-elections-takeaways-intl/index.html): "In the UK, the Brexit Party, led by arch-Brexiteer Nigel Farage, took home 31.71% of the vote. This is almost equivalent to the vote share of the Labour Party and the Liberal Democrats combined and reflects growing dissatisfaction with traditional UK parties. It's worth noting that the Brexit Party took most of its seats from the UK Independence Party, Farage's previous political vehicle."

Comment: FWIW, [Euronews](https://www.euronews.com/2019/05/27/did-brexit-parties-really-win-in-the-european-elections): "Including the Conservatives with Brexit-supporting parties received roughly 45% of the vote, whereas Remain parties received 39%. If the Labour party were to move into the remain camp it would give that side a clear majority with roughly 53% of the vote."

Comment: @Fizz unless that caused voters to move their support. The same logic would give leave a clear win if Labour moved that way. At this point I am sort of assuming that the numbers for Red/Blue in this election represent those that will never change their vote no matter what.

Comment: @Jontia If the Tories remain, half of Britain hates them and will never forgive them. If they leave without deal, I'd say 65% will never forgive them, same if they leave with a deal. So I guess they'll go for a second referendum and get rid of the responsibility. The other thing the can do is re-elections, but that would be fatal for them.

Comment: @Jontia A very large section of the Conservative party is totally opposed to Brexit. You can be sure that the rump Conservative vote - that which was not plundered by the Brexit Party was substantially composed of Remainers.

Comment: @Fizz The CNN comment is largely irrelevant, as it is simply informing a mostly American audience of some of the basic facts about British politics.

Comment: The Brexit party actually got a smaller number of votes than the petition to revoke Article 50, for comparison.

Comment: @WS2 there was little evidence for your assertion during the indicative votes https://ig.ft.com/brexit-second-round-indicative-votes/ . Unless you're talking about the party membership at large ?

Comment: @Jontia I was not talking about the party membership - average age 70 - which is notoriously right-wing and Brexit minded. I was thinking more of the Conservative electorate, and clearly did not put it as well as I should have. There are also a number of MPs - not just Ken Clarke, Dominic Grieve and Phillip Lee.

Comment: Perhaps the commentary about "winning" and "losing" were more comparisons of pre- and post- election status, and whether any party made gains or losses.

Comment: So, your question is that when you start adding a whole bunch of parties together, that which is true of single parties no longer applies? Well, yes, that often happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To summarize what I wrote in several comments...

- The least controversial conclusion about this election was that both Labour and the Conservatives got punished at the polls. Labor lost half their (MEP) seats, i.e. went from 20 to 10. The Conservatives lost even more, 15 seats, being left with just 4; their worst ever EU-election results. So clearly these two parties are among (if not the main) losers of this election.
- On the avowed remain front: The Lib Dems are clearly a big winner in terms of swing, going from just one MEP to 16. And to a lesser extent so were the Greens from 4 to 7 and the SNP gaining one MEP for a total of 3 now. Plaid didn't make any inroads, keeping their only MEP. The new party Change UK didn't get any. In total this remain group has 27 MEPs now.
- On the avowed (hard) Brexit front: The new Brexit party indeed is the largest winner as a single party with 29 MEPs; they outdo the avowed remain parties by 2 seats. But in terms of swing it gets dicy: the UKIP lost all of its 24 seats! So the net gain in this camp was only 5 seats, a much less significant momentum. If Wikipedia is correct on this issue that 14 former UKIP MEPs had already formally switched to the Brexit Party before the election, then the swing of the Brexit Party itself in the election is only 15 seats (on par with the Lib Dems).
- Finally, there's the thorny issue how to peg the Conservatives and Labour in terms of pro- or anti-Brexit. As the BBC pegged these two parties, they were internally divided on Brexit, so the BBC didn't count them toward either pro- or against-Brexit. As Euronews ultimately [pegged them](https://www.euronews.com/2019/05/27/did-brexit-parties-really-win-in-the-european-elections), the Conservatives were pro and Labour against. Given Corbyn's' post-election [endorsement](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/may/27/jeremy-corbyn-signals-more-support-for-second-referendum-after-voter-exodus) of a [2nd] referendum, Euronews was perhaps somewhat right in this assessment, at least in the future tense. But the BBC argument that the parties which were indecisive and/or ineffective vis-a-vis of Brexit prior to the election got punished is also strengthened by this post-election change of stance of Labour.

The analysis is slightly different if one uses vote shares instead of seats; the BBC has done the former already (and it's included in your post). The Brexit Party was however more effective in transforming a lesser vote share into more seats than the avowed remain parties. Also of note, geographically, (outside of NI) the Brexit Party came in first everywhere but in Scotland or London.

N.B. here's a compact numerical summary of the election [from the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/ng-interactive/2019/may/26/european-election-latest-results-2019-uk-england-scotland-wales-ni-eu-parliament), which doesn't include the Northern Ireland parties in this chart; the latter are 1:1:1 split on MEP seats between APNI, DUP and Sinn Fein; I think of these only DUP is pro-Brexit, the other two NI parties have campaigned against it. The vote share figures are not available for Northern Ireland, because it uses STV.

[image]

A video analysis has now been [posted](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/uk-politics-48428662/what-do-the-european-election-results-tell-us-about-uk-politics) by the BBC online, which is a bit more dynamic than what they had before. They also posted a (text) [analysis](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-48427839) for Northern Ireland. According to that, mirroring results in rest of the UK, the UUP took a beating (lost their seat to the anti-Brexit Alliance) because of the UUP's unclear stance on Brexit.

Answer (score 7):

There is no official definiton for "dominate." Using that word, especially in a media context, is a value judgement.

- One could easily say that the party with the largest single vote count "dominated" the election. That's Brexit.
- One could easily say that the party with the largest single number of seats "dominated" the election. That's Brexit.
- One could easily say that the party with the largest increase in seats or votes "dominated" the election. That's Brexit.

Right now I can think of no definition how any other party "dominated" the election.

Comment: How could the Brexit Party increase their number of seats when it is the first time they have ever stood? They didn't even exist last time.

Comment: Also from what you say perhaps the choice of the world "dominated" was not the best.

Comment: Any other use of the word dominate would I agree be nonsensical. The question for me is if the party that has done the best can be described as dominating, when as a single issue party those in direct opposition to that view, totalled together, surpass them. To be clear that is not pro-Brexit, it is pro-No deal Brexit.

Comment: @Jontia, the OP asked about the reasoning behind the word choice in a news article. That's borderline off-topic here because it asks about the motivation of people, not hard facts, but I decided to present a few logical explanations. Neither of us is editing the BBC news for style and grammar, I suppose.

Comment: @user the Brexit party is the real inheritor of UKIP, through its key media figure and fundraiser Nigel Farage. The "continuity UKIP" kept the name but got no seats and a small fraction of the vote. The extent to which Brexit is a *personal* phenomenon around Farage as a media figure should not be understated - note the lack of conventional party infrastructure, party democracy etc.

Comment: If you consider that by the time of the election 14 former UKIP MEPS had formally defected to the Brexit Party, then their seat share increased by 29 - 14 = 15 seats. 
The Libdems only had one MEP seat in 2014 (and before the 2019 election). So their seat surge was 16 -1 =15, equal to the Brexit Party. If you consider the Brexit Party the wholesale successor of UKIP, which had 24 MEPs in 2014, then Brexit Party surge is a lot less spectacular.

Comment: You are right to the extent that no other single party "dominated" the elections, but the Brexit party. However it is perfectly clear that in a more general sense the principle of remaining in the EU dominated the elections.

Comment: This answer seems to presuppose that there must be a party which dominated, but is that how people use the word? One could "*easily say*" that a party which got more than two thirds of the votes or seats dominated, but how many people would say that a party which won a three-way election 34-33-33 had "dominated"? Without some kind of argument (or, better, evidence) for appropriate thresholds, the claims made in the first sentence of each bullet point are *prima facie* false.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, the OP asked if the BBC headline was a "reasonable" interpretation. That is a lower standard than "the best" or "the only" interpretation.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I don't think the answer reaches that standard. It gives three interpretations which on the face of it seem unreasonable (unless "dominate" means "win by any margin, however small") and doesn't attempt to justify why they are reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

> (...explicitly pro-remain parties (Lib Dems, Greens, Plaid, SNP, Change UK).

The biggest logical problem with this assessment is that these parties exist outside of the context of Brexit. These parties were going to get votes no matter what, even if the topic of Brexit never existed and the phrase hadn't ever been coined. They might have (in that alternate reality) even had this same kind of success at this moment in history. They have existed, in some form, decades before Brexit happened and even before the UK joined the EU. Their central policies have always been explicit and clear, with the exception of maybe the Liberal Democrats early on. Sure, many of the people voting for those parties may have been voting for them because of their stance on the current event of Brexit, but many certainly only voted for these parties because of their central agendas independent of any other issues of the day.

On the other hand, there's only one reason why somebody voted for the Brexit party or Change UK. There is no other reason to vote for those parties. They didn't even exist 3 months ago! That's why people are saying that the Brexit party 'dominated'. It's one-topic policy has taken the day as far as this election is concerned. Change UK barely registered. The Remain vote certainly had a large influence on those aforementioned parties. But it is the absolute clarity of all these party's respective positions that are the reason for their success. Nobody has any doubt what any of these parties would do if they were in power, and nobody thinks they would compromise on those dearly held principles, nor betray eventually even themselves the way the Conservative and Labour Parties appear to have done. And I think it is a dangerous place of complacency if the media and politicians keep putting this narrative forward that 'Remain' parties beat the 'Brexit' party.

Comment: By the same token, the Brexit Party (Note, not actually a party) ran a campaign with no actual policies to turn voters away. The Remain vs Leave narrative is not purely a media invention though, the Lib Dem manifesto for this election was actually titled "Bollocks to Brexit".

Comment: What do you mean "not actually a party". The Brexit Party is registered as an official party in the UK.

Comment: It has no members, no party framework, no manifesto. It is purely a vehicle for one man's rhetoric.

Comment: It had a manifesto for the European Parliament elections; it does have a [party framework](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0010/254791/FOI-030-19-Response.pdf). I have no idea how many members it has (I'm not one), but you are entirely wrong about it not being a party.

Answer (score 2):

This hinges on the definition of *dominate*. From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dominate):

> **dominate**
>   ​to be the largest, most important, or most noticeable part of something

Since the Brexit party got the largest share of the vote, then yes, it is accurate to say they dominated the election.

Comment: Even though they were significantly beaten by the explicitly pro-remain parties? Sounds like they were comprehensively and decisively beaten, their only policy being a hard brexit having been rejected by a large majority.

Comment: @user Yes, *dominate* here simply means largest, it doesn't mean "larger than all others put together".

Comment: @user You seem to be looking for confirmation of your POV only - which is a valid reason to close your question. Please stay neutral if you ask a question.

Comment: @Sjoerd please be respectful and don't make unfounded accusations. I am merely exploring the issue and rising a reasonable question that seems to undermine the answer. See here for guidance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: @user Please be more open for valid criticism. See here for guidance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: @Sjoerd please use comments to offer constructive criticism in a non-accusatory manner. See here for guidance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct